# Create Popup Image with share button

Tags: javascript, html, image, css, popup

I want to make the popup image gallery with facebook and twitter share button, but I do not know how to make it.

[image: image popup]

Does anyone have a reference tutorial?

Thanks in advance,

Regards :)

Comment: What do you mean by popup image with facebook and twitter button. Are there any similar things you have seen?! or can you provide an image to see what you really need?!

Comment: here is a simple example: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/12/08/inspiration-dialog-effects/ . you can use these dialog effects with everything you want

Comment: Thanks for reply, my post has been edited. so,  when the popup image gallery, to the right of the image will be the share button. usefulness just to share to social media.

Comment: In the link I have provided there is a script that you can use to have a pop up or dialog box. then inside the script you can use a div for your image and another for you social media buttons. then you can use `float:right` style for your buttons and `float:left` style for you image. That's it.

Comment: can it, if I click the first image, a popup will display image 1. if i click image 2, a popup will display image 2 ?? I actually just part of the frontend development. I just do not want to bother part backend development. :)

Answer (score 1):

Please check this tutorial. Its flexible and easy to use http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/

Comment: Thanks for reply, i'll figure it out.. :)

Comment: hi @kumar , i think i got problem with plugin fancyapps, when image be pop-up. image will display with size original, wheter it can be custom ? i mean, if size original w: 150px h: 150px, when display popup be w: 500px, h: 500px. I've tried changing the code css , but it's doesn't work..

Comment: you can choose this option http://prntscr.com/6eymcd and add set required height/width on parent div.

Answer (score 0):

this my inline script :

```
<script> 
            $(".fancybox")
            .attr('rel', 'gallery')
            .fancybox({
                beforeShow: function () {
                    if (this.title) {
                    // New line
                    this.title += '<br />';

                    this.title += '<p> Vote : 0 </p>'

                    // Add vote button
                    this.title += '<button class="btn-oi custom-vote"><span>Vote</span></button> ';

                    // Add share fb button
                    this.title += '<button class="btn-oi custom-fb icon-fb"><span>Share</span></button>';

                    // Add share tweet button
                    this.title += '<button class="btn-oi custom-twit icon-twit"><span>Share</span></button>';


                    }
                },
                helpers : {
                    title : {
                        type: 'inside'
                    }
                }  
            });

</script>
```

this my html :

```
<div id="member-gallery" class="col-xs-12 col-md-7">
   <div class="title-template gallery-left"> Member Gallery </div>

   <div class="row">

       <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 item gallery">
        <a title="Ramanda Chairina" class="fancybox" href="img/logo-1.jpg">
        <img src="img/logo-1.jpg" alt=""/> <!-- size original w: 320px h: 260px -->
        </a>
       </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```